# Elasticsearch query - combining queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch and Kibana 6.2.4.  I have following queries that retrieve data for the conditions that: (1) Give me all records where endUtc does not exist; (2) Give me all the records if endUtc has value set to greater than the current timestamp retrieved from the system.

```
GET /session/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": { 
        "exists": {
          "field": "endUtc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And...

```
GET /session/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "endUtc": {
        "gt": "<Current date/time>"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am having problem combining the two queries together. Is there any ES query expert out there knows how to make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bool-query.html

Your query might be like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "endUtc"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "endUtc": {
              "gt": "<Current date/time>"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```